# Why does "User Contributed Perl Documentation" show up when I look for 'man' pages

Tags: osx, path, man, darwin

When I

```
man -f <some string>
```

in addition to the expected Unix man pages, I get a bunch of odd looking entries that all have the header "User Contributed Perl Documentation". For example

```
man -f ip
```

in addition to things like

```
ip(4)            - Internet Protocol
ip2cc(1)         - lookup country from IP address or hostname
ipconfig(8)      - view and control IP configuration state
...
```

also lists things like

```
IP::Authority(3pm)       - fast lookup of authority by IP address
IP::Country(3pm)         - fast lookup of country codes from IP addresses
IP::Country::Fast(3pm)   - fast lookup of country codes by IP address
IP::Country::MaxMind(3pm) - Look up country by IP Address
IP::Country::Medium(3pm) - cached lookup of country codes by IP address and domain name
```

all of which are idenfified as "User Contributed Perl Documentation".

My 'man' path (from `man --path`), on OS X 10.8.2 is

```
/usr/local/git/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/usr/texbin/man
```

which is the same as it is on other machines that don't show these additional pages.

Where are these coming from? Can I limit my results to only Unix shell pages by default?

Comment: i think it acts recursively!

Comment: `man 1 string` searches for `string` in Section 1 only. (Not sure about OSX, some platforms make that `-s 1`.)

Comment: ... Though by the looks of your "acceptable" results, you only want to exclude section 3 really.

Comment: @tripleee: That doesn't seem to work with `-f`. Should it?

Comment: IMHO it "should" but don't expect Apple to take your bug report very seriously. One of the drawbacks of a commercial OS vendor.

Comment: Try `man -w` to see where a man page is picked up from. Furthermore [`man -s 1 man`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html) is worth a read if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl encourages library authors to include documentation in [pod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Documentation) format in each source file. This documentation can be translater automatically to other formats including man pages, and many systems provide the documentation of installed Perl modules as man pages.

Man pages of Perl modules are in section `3pm`. You can skip the whole of section 3 (library functions of any language) by passing the `-S` option to man and specifying a value that doesn't include 3, e.g.

```
man -S 1:8:4:5:6:7 foo
```

Setting the `MANSECT` environment variable has the same effect. I don't think there's a way to exclude section 3pm while retaining section 3 on OSX.

Comment: On OS X, `-S` appears to be ignored when used with `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

Those are manpages for Perl modules (dead giveaway: the `3pm` is section 3 (library functions), *P*erl *M*odule), most of which are user-contributed to Perl (look at [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org)), together with their documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to "skip" them? Where are they located and how are they picked up, given my `man` path?

Comment: For a long time, the footer text was hard-coded in `pod2man`. These days, if your Perl is not precambric (something like 5.6 I would guess) you can pass in an option to override it, but apparently the build script for these man pages don't do that. File a bug report and wait a couple of years, or perform severe overkill and rebuild them from source locally.